# How to make mercurial sort the output of `hg log` by commit date?

Tags: mercurial

How can I make mercurial order the output of `hg log` by commit date?

The output seems to be ordered by the date I pull the commits into my repository instead of when they were committed.

Comment: I.e. a flag equivalent to git's `--date-order`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a revset:

```
$ hg log -r 'sort(all(), date)'
```

If you want to see the most recent commits first, do:

```
$ hg log -r 'sort(all(), -date)'
```

See `hg help -v revsets` for more details.

Comment: Answers the question, but it breaks with the `-G` option.

Comment: Asked a separate question for doing the same thing for the graph log: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270988/how-to-make-mercurial-sort-the-output-of-hg-log-g-by-commit-date

Comment: I don’t think it makes sense for -G to display any order but DAG order.

Comment: When converting a DAG to a list there are many ways to do it that still preserve the invariant that a child is listed before its parent. Since a child commit cannot be committed before its parent ordering by commit date is one of those valid methods. Git allows you to do  this with `git log --graph --data-order`.

Comment: editing a commit would change its hash, so every descendant commit would need to be updated to still be descendant of the newly edited commit.