# How to make mercurial sort the output of `hg log -G` by commit date?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

How can I make mercurial order the graph log output of `hg log -G` by commit date?

Using `hg log -r 'sort(all(), -date)'` works without the graph log option as answered in [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269015/how-to-make-mercurial-sort-the-output-of-hg-log-by-commit-date)], but that solution doesn't seem to have any effect on the order of the graph log.

I'm looking for a mercurial equivalent of `git log --graph --date-order`.

Comment: I haven't really been keeping up with hg these days, but I don't think you can. Mercurial's graph code has always seemed pretty weak to me (Git's is terrible internally, but at least provides this kind of sorting).